# How to make a button a linear gradient color border in tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying Nextjs and tailwind css i created a simple page with that but now i am facing a problem that i want to make the button a linear gradient color border in tailwind css how can i do that with my code?

```
     <Link href={'/about'}>
        <button className="bg-black-500 hover:bg-blue-700 mt-5 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full border border-blue-500 shadow-md transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105">
          Learn More
        </button>
      </Link>
```

Comment: Here is an example of a gradient border: https://www.dhairyashah.dev/posts/how-to-create-gradient-border-with-tailwind-css/

Comment: @BrijeshBhakta Can you please give me a simple code example? i saw that blog post how to do things in my code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code to make your button's background into a linear gradient:

```html
    <button class="bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-purple-500 text-white font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded">
      Gradient Button
    </button>
```

You can find the detailed explanation about the tailwind CSS linear gradient classes here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#linear-gradients

If you want to make it look like it has its border as the linear gradient color then you can try something like this:

```html
<button class="bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-purple-500 text-white font-semibold rounded p-1">
  <span class="flex w-full bg-gray-900 text-white rounded p-2">
  Gradient border
     </span>
</button>
```

It needs you to create another element inside it which will take the background color of the parent container where it resides and our main button will have a full bg gradient. That will create an illusion of having a border gradient. I am sure there might be other ways, including using pseudo-elements to create this effect.

Comment: Thanks this works well for  Gradient border code how can i make it like when a user hover over it hover over with a Gradient background color

Comment: Sure. You can add a `group` class on the button element and `group-hover:bg-transparent` class on the span element. That way when the user will hover over the button the full gradient will be visible instead of the border. You can learn more about it here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by using `bg-gradient-to` class with `from` and `to` colors.

For example :

```
<Link href="/about">
  <button className="relative mt-5 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full overflow-hidden shadow-md transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105">
    <span className="relative z-10">Learn More</span>
    <span className="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-green-500 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full"></span>
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: I am saying to say that How can i make the border linear gradient its making the whole color background color linear gradient

Comment: @cwecae, now please check and let me know if this meets your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for trying the but the above code by @Vibhor works